# .CS files and containing folders are missing in TFS 2010 build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

I have a Visual studio 2013 MVC project. And I have different folders like...

- Images - contains only images
- Views - contains cshtml files
- Scripts - contains js files
- Models - only cs files
- Controllers - only cs files
- app_start - only cs files

But after the build, I am getting only images,scripts, views and global.asax folders and files in the drop location.

I couldn't find any cs files and related folders.

Can any one please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

.cs files are uncompiled, during the build these will be compiled into a DLL with the same name as the project that contains them, this will end up in the bin folder